# API для подсказок при вводе адреса

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как лучше реализовать ввод пользователем адреса доставки? Использую React. Адрес вводится в input. Но можно сделать подсказку. Когда вводишь символ в input предлагаются сразу варианты, чтобы человеку не нужно было долго писать. Как это осуществить? Каким инструментом пользоваться? Что посоветуете?

Comment: Супер! Не вносить же всевозможные варианты подсказок в базу

Comment: Если нужен сервис для подсказок при вводе адреса, можете попробовать написать в гугле "api для подсказок при вводе адреса"

Answer (score 1):

На событие ввода символа (а лучше спустя небольшой таймаут) вешаешь обработчик, который спрашивает у сервера об api варианты значений, подходящих под введённые символы. Результат рендеришь в "выпадающем меню".

Ну а вообще, можно конечно воспользоваться вот этим: https://kladr-api.ru/examples

Comment: К сожалению тут только русский язык, что мне не подходит. Но ссылка полезная сама по себе, спасибо

Comment: https://www.nominatim.org/release-docs/develop/api/Search/ - может вот это подойдёт?

Answer (score 1):

Вот хорошая библиотека [React Autosuggest](http://react-autosuggest.js.org/) Ссылка на рабочий пример [codepen](https://codepen.io/moroshko/pen/vpBzMr)

```js
const languages = [
  {
    name: 'C',
    year: 1972
  },
  {
    name: 'C#',
    year: 2000
  },
  {
    name: 'C++',
    year: 1983
  },
  {
    name: 'Clojure',
    year: 2007
  },
  {
    name: 'Elm',
    year: 2012
  },
  {
    name: 'Go',
    year: 2009
  },
  {
    name: 'Haskell',
    year: 1990
  },
  {
    name: 'Java',
    year: 1995
  },
  {
    name: 'Javascript',
    year: 1995
  },
  {
    name: 'Perl',
    year: 1987
  },
  {
    name: 'PHP',
    year: 1995
  },
  {
    name: 'Python',
    year: 1991
  },
  {
    name: 'Ruby',
    year: 1995
  },
  {
    name: 'Scala',
    year: 2003
  }
];

// https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_Special_Characters
const escapeRegexCharacters = str => str.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');

const getSuggestions = value => {
  const escapedValue = escapeRegexCharacters(value.trim());
  
  if (escapedValue === '') {
    return [];
  }

  const regex = new RegExp('^' + escapedValue, 'i');
  const suggestions = languages.filter(language => regex.test(language.name));
  
  if (suggestions.length === 0) {
    return [
      { isAddNew: true }
    ];
  }
  
  return suggestions;
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      value: '',
      suggestions: []
    };    
  }

  onChange = (event, { newValue, method }) => {
    this.setState({
      value: newValue
    });
  };

  getSuggestionValue = suggestion => {
    if (suggestion.isAddNew) {
      return this.state.value;
    }
    
    return suggestion.name;
  };

  renderSuggestion = suggestion => {
    if (suggestion.isAddNew) {
      return (
        <span>
          [+] Add new: <strong>{this.state.value}</strong>
        </span>
      );
    }

    return suggestion.name;
  };
  
  onSuggestionsFetchRequested = ({ value }) => {
    this.setState({
      suggestions: getSuggestions(value)
    });
  };

  onSuggestionsClearRequested = () => {
    this.setState({
      suggestions: []
    });
  };

  onSuggestionSelected = (event, { suggestion }) => {
    if (suggestion.isAddNew) {
      console.log('Add new:', this.state.value);
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { value, suggestions } = this.state;
    const inputProps = {
      placeholder: "Type 'c'",
      value,
      onChange: this.onChange
    };

    return (
      <Autosuggest 
        suggestions={suggestions}
        onSuggestionsFetchRequested={this.onSuggestionsFetchRequested}
        onSuggestionsClearRequested={this.onSuggestionsClearRequested}
        getSuggestionValue={this.getSuggestionValue}
        renderSuggestion={this.renderSuggestion}
        onSuggestionSelected={this.onSuggestionSelected}
        inputProps={inputProps} 
      />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.react-autosuggest__container {
  position: relative;
}

.react-autosuggest__input {
  width: 240px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.react-autosuggest__input--focused {
  outline: none;
}

.react-autosuggest__input--open {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

.react-autosuggest__suggestions-container {
  display: none;
}

.react-autosuggest__suggestions-container--open {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 51px;
  width: 280px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.react-autosuggest__suggestions-list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.react-autosuggest__suggestion {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.react-autosuggest__suggestion--highlighted {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.footer {
  margin: 9px 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #777;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/15.4.2/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-autosuggest@9.0.0/dist/standalone/autosuggest.js"></script>
<h2>Add new option</h2>
<div id="app"></div>
```